# jsPDF and html2canvas image squished?

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm currently trying to generate a PDF of a div on my website. I have the basic functionality complete; however, when I download the PDF, the contents of my div are squished and stretched instead of an exact match of my website. Attached is the code I'm using and screenshots of the PDFs and website:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="header" id="nodeToRenderAsPDF" style="padding: 150px 0 150px 0">
    <h2><%=companyName%>, your PDF will begin downloading!</h2>
    <p>Thanks for submitting your information. We hope you enjoy!</p>
    <button id="pdfDownloadButton">Download PDF</button>
    <a href="javascript:print()">Download PDF</a>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/js.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

...and the JS:

```
function print(quality = 2) {
    const filename  = 'ThisIsYourPDFFilename.pdf';

    html2canvas(document.querySelector('#nodeToRenderAsPDF'), 
                            {scale: quality}
                     ).then(canvas => {
        let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
        pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0, 0, 211, 298);
        pdf.save(filename);
    });
}

$("#pdfDownloadButton").on("click", print);
```

And some screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuzwT.jpg

Any ideas for how I may fix this are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this, but you could try specifying a width and a height. Cuz it just seems as if the div doesn't fit on the pdf page. The div has a waaay higher width than the standard size of a pdf document. Let me know if that helps.

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector('#nodeToRenderAsPDF', {
  width: 1200,
  height: 400
}).then(function(canvas) {
  let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
  pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0, 0, 211, 298);
  pdf.save(filename);
});
```